# Java - configure Object properties

Tags: java, configuration, properties, runtime, configuration-files

I would like to configure an object's properties at runtime either via a properties file, possibly XML (even though it can be a little more verbose).  The properties may be nested, so I think I would use something like Apache's Bean Utils.

I was wondering what other formats are out there instead of properties and xml.

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- YAML http://www.yaml.org/
- JSON http://www.json.org/

Comment: +1 for JSON. I'm not a big fan of indent-sensitive YAML though.

Comment: Well modern YAML can actually be written with curly braces and ends up being mostly upward-compatible from JSON. Plus YAML is a lot richer and allows encoding of data types, re-references, etc.